# Saving a particular sheet from one workbook to another in a particular folder

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to save a particular worksheet from my working workbook to another workbook, and trying to save it in the path of my current workbook. The saving option is in such a way that it should get saved with the dd.mm.yyyy.

I tried the following code and I am getting application defined error in the line

```
> newWB.SaveAs filename:=Path2 & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") &
> myWorksheets(i), FileFormat:=xlsx
```

Could you please help me figure out where I am wrong?

```
Sub save()
 Dim myWorksheets() As String 'Array to hold worksheet names to copy
 Dim newWB As Workbook
 Dim CurrWB As Workbook
 Dim i As Integer
Dim path1, Path2
path1 = ThisWorkbook.Path
Path2 = path1 & "\TT"
 Set CurrWB = ThisWorkbook
 myWorksheets = Split("Report", ",")
 For i = LBound(myWorksheets) To UBound(myWorksheets) 'Go through entire array
      Set newWB = Workbooks.Add 'Create new workbook
      CurrWB.Sheets(Trim(myWorksheets(i))).Copy
      newWB.SaveAs filename:=Path2 & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & myWorksheets(i), FileFormat:=xlsx
      newWB.Close saveChanges:=False
 Next i
 CurrWB.Save 'save original workbook.
 End Sub
```

Comment: At first glance, I would say the `FileFormat` parameter you are passing it is not correct.

Comment: Also keep in mind that your path needs to end with a backslash.

Comment: This probably isn't the full problem but define `Dim path1 as String, path2 as String`

Comment: Before asking new questions, always find some time to close your old questions by selecting the working solutions. You have too many open questions.

Comment: @sktneer I have already marked the answer for my question which I found useful

Comment: @PGCodeRider the problem is there are two workbooks opening with my code. And the first workbook is getting saved and closed while the data where it is copied still remains the same

Comment: If the offered solutions don't resolve your issue, always leave a feedback under each offered solution. That's a good habit. The askers, who don't follow this, are easily ignored by many experts as they don't get any feedback for the answer they provide. :)

Comment: You might want to consider using the `ThisWorkbook` function which isolates the code that's being run to the file where the macro exists?

Comment: @sktneer I think I offered an Feeback that it doesn't work . I will make sure I will follow it :)

Comment: @sktneer could you offer me a solution for this ?

Comment: @PGCodeRider I am not getting your point. can you provide me an example

Comment: @Jenny you may want to consider sktneer's point. In this thread you have at least 3 decent suggestions, none of which you have officially marked as helpful. Your other questions listed have several good answers that you haven't accepted. Doesn't offer much incentive to help you out. Best of luck. I'll check back later.

Comment: @PGCodeRider when they don't work for me I cant give them as accepted. and I have given the feedback when it dint work. I guess you should have a look again on my post. You cant blame me just like that

Comment: @PGCodeRider I got it solved , thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

@Jenny - This code will accomplish what you ask in your question, it will save the ActiveSheet as a new file; and can be used as a function the can be called within your code. You can change the "Rpt" to identify the title of the new workbook. When I'm writing vba code, I always try to follow what my mother use to say to me, "Keep it simple".

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim wbPath As String
wbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    ActiveSheet.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=wbPath & "\" & "Rpt" & " " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=51, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: I will try and get back to you